# Using one command button (search button) to open two sub-form in one form via VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two table, one form and two sub-form. In the form, I have search button and the output must come out in two sub-forms. Only success to open 1 sub-form. The other sub-form does't change anything. All happen in one form. The question is how do i make when i hit button search, two sub-form come out the output that i want. For example, i want to search apple. two sub-form will give me apple. Of course in both table have apple.

```
Private Sub Command15_Click()
Dim mySiteID As String
mySiteID = "Select * from Access_FullSite where([Site ID] = '" & Me.Text27 & "')"
Me.Access_FullSite_subform.Form.RecordSource = mySiteID
Me.Access_FullSite_subform.Form.Requery

Dim mySiteID As String
mySiteID = "Select * from Access_FullSite where([Site ID] = '" & Me.Text27 & "')"
Me.Metro_CP_subform.Form.RecordSource = mySiteID
Me.Metro_CP_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: @Trix my question is how do i make when i hit button search, two sub-form come out the output that i want. For example, i want to search apple. two sub-form will give me apple. Of course in both table have apple.

Comment: Please edit your question with the full, actual code. The code you posted doesn't compile, it will give the `Duplicate declaration in current scope` error.

Comment: @Andre Thanks... and how do i get the code to compile? I think ive missing the code somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess here based on your incomplete question, but I think what you're after is

```
 Private Sub Command15_Click()
 Dim mySiteID As String
 mySiteID = "Select * from Access_FullSite where([Site ID] = '" & Me.Text27 & "')"
 Me.Access_FullSite_subform.Form.RecordSource = mySiteID
 Me.Access_FullSite_subform.Form.Requery
 Me.Metro_CP_subform.Form.RecordSource = mySiteID
 Me.Metro_CP_subform.Form.Requery
 End Sub
```

You don't need to re-declare (which will fail the compile) or set the variable to the same value.